# jQuery Isotope/Masonry Cornerstamp in center of page

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

JQuery Masonry and Isotope allow you to have a Cornerstamp that is static while the rest of the page is dynamic.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/masonry-corner-stamp.html

However, I'd like the static area to be a block on the center of the page (not a straight column, just a block in the middle of the page, which to the bottom and side are dynamic).

Does anyone know if this is possible or whether I should be looking for other jquery plugins instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with masonry, it is only possible to have the corner stamp on the side.

Comment: That sucks.  Any other suggestions for how to have a centered "corner stamp"?

Comment: It depends on how you layout looks. The only way I can now think of to keep the stamp in the middle would probably be to change its order accordingly to number of columns. If you can post an example or picture it would be easier to answer.

Comment: adam is right, you can not have a centered corner stamp with Masonry and Isotope for that matter.